# Collecting GroupFlux into a Hashmap by the keys

Tags: java, project-reactor

I've recently started using Project Reactor and I've come up with a scenario I can't seem to figure out.

Basically I would like to group a certain stream and then obtain the hash-map such as `grouping key -> List of grouped values`. I've been playing around with the API but the furthest I've got is either obtaining the values, or the keys or the count, but not the data structure I want. This would be the code, for example, to obtain the values:

```
var elements = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Flux.just(-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3)
        .groupBy(val -> val.compareTo(0))
        .flatMap(Flux::collectList)
        .subscribe(elements::addAll);
```

The test I would like to pass is the following:

```
@Test
public void groupBy() {
    var elements = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();

    Flux.just(-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3)
            .groupBy(val -> val.compareTo(0))
            // Do something here ...
            .subscribe(...);

    assertThat(elements).containsKeys(-1, 1);
    assertThat(elements.get(-1)).containsExactly(-1, -2, -3);
    assertThat(elements.get(1)).containsExactly(1, 2, 3);
}
```

How could I achieve the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [Flux#connect](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)? It accepts `Collector`, the same type as `Stream` uses. There is also `Flux#collectMap`.

Plus, in case you need to **stream** such map, you can use [Flux#scan](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#scan-A-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

`groupBy` is helpful when you need to "route" your signals by key and have a `Flux` by key, but it is not designed to be used for creating collections of data.

Comment: I had a feeling that I was forcing a little bit the `groupBy`, but I wasn't sure. Thanks for the suggestions!